# How can I stylish html5 validation message?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi now I am looking for form validation. I know that HTML5 validation is a good option for me. But this validation message color is not match for my theme. So is any way to stylish this message? I need a green background with red color. How can I customize it?

[image]

My code

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form>
            Enter your E-mail<input type="email" name="email">
            <input type='submit'>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: get the id of validation message div and apply styling using css

Comment: @PandiyanCool here I can't see any div  of validation message. Are sure about the div?

Comment: Use web inspector to inspect element

Comment: I am using fedora 14 and Google chrome when I inspect it here I can't see any extra element.

Answer (score 4):

> So Is there any way to style this message? I need a green background with red color. How can I customize it?

You can't style the message box itself, as it is built into the browser. The styling and presentation of these messages will differ between browsers.

If you want something that you can style, you are going to have to write the validation yourself and add DOM elements that are select-able.

Comment: Are you sure? I never saw any browser give out a default message like that...

Comment: @bjb568 You will see the messages in supported browsers. View this example in Chrome/FF http://jsfiddle.net/hQLD8/ It's like asking to style an alert or prompt; it's added by the Chrome browser.

Comment: You might want to reword your answer a bit. The way it currently reads it pertains to the message itself, not the message box.

Comment: Oh. That picture is from Chrome.